# Doctrine2: Could not convert database value to .... Doctrine Type JSON

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm relatively new to Doctrine since I've only taken over this project temporarily, and I've hit a wall troubleshooting where the query went wrong. So, please bear with me.

The query goes like this:

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery(<<<'DQL' SELECT t FROM App\Domain\UserAccount\TransactionLog\Transaction t JOIN t.userAccount u WHERE u.id = :id AND t.type.value IN (:types) ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC, t.type.value ASC DQL )


    $query->setParameter('id', $id);
    $query->setParameter('types', $types);

    $query->setFirstResult($offset);
    $query->setMaxResults($total);
    return $query->getArrayResult();`
```

here, the named parameter **types** is an array of Enum called **TransactionType**.

This query basically works for all the **userAccount**s, but for only one user, it's giving me error saying: `Could not convert database value "{"requestData": {"bi..." to Doctrine Type json`.

I checked the prepared statements and parameters for different users, and they are all similar, except for the **id** parameter of course.

The prepared statement:

> SELECT t0_.timestamp AS timestamp_0, t0_.details AS details_1, t0_.id AS id_2, t0_.type_value AS type_value_3, t0_.licence_code AS licence_code_4, t0_.balance_value_amount AS balance_value_amount_5, t0_.balance_value_currency_code AS balance_value_currency_code_6, t0_.balance_frozen_amount AS balance_frozen_amount_7, t0_.balance_frozen_currency_code AS balance_frozen_currency_code_8, t0_.balance_bonus_amount AS balance_bonus_amount_9, t0_.balance_bonus_currency_code AS balance_bonus_currency_code_10, t0_.balance_currency_code AS balance_currency_code_11, t0_.change_value_amount AS change_value_amount_12, t0_.change_value_currency_code AS change_value_currency_code_13, t0_.change_frozen_amount AS change_frozen_amount_14, t0_.change_frozen_currency_code AS change_frozen_currency_code_15, t0_.change_bonus_amount AS change_bonus_amount_16, t0_.change_bonus_currency_code AS change_bonus_currency_code_17, t0_.gameId_id AS gameId_id_18, t0_.creditChangeInEuro_amount AS creditChangeInEuro_amount_19, t0_.creditChangeInEuro_currency_code AS creditChangeInEuro_currency_code_20, t0_.className AS className_21, t0_.userAccount_id AS userAccount_id_22 FROM transactions t0_ INNER JOIN userAccount u1_ ON t0_.userAccount_id = u1_.id WHERE (u1_.id = ? AND t0_.type_value IN (?)) AND t0_.className IN ('transaction', 'gamerelatedtransaction') ORDER BY t0_.timestamp DESC, t0_.type_value ASC LIMIT 30

The parameters:

> Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#562
> -elements: array:2 [
> 0 => Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter {#558
> -name: "id"
> -value: "19819-1"
> -type: 2
> -typeSpecified: false
> }
> 1 => Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter {#559
> -name: "types"
> -value: array:51 [
> "TEAM_PAID" => "TEAM_PAID"
> "TEAM_PAID_REVERTED" => "TEAM_PAID_REVERTED"
> "TEAM_PAYMENT_BONUS_APPLIED" => "TEAM_PAYMENT_BONUS_APPLIED"
> ]
> -type: 102
> -typeSpecified: true
> }
> ]
> }

Right now, I'm really scratching my head because why only it fails on this specific user but not on others.

For the **types** parameter, I tried the following:

- Including `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY` in the setParameter() function.
- converting the array of enums to array of enum's values (e.g., array_values($types))